# Splitting file name in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have  files in one folder with following naming convention

`ClientID_ClientName_Date_Fileextension`

- 12345_Dell_20110103.CSV

I want to extract ClientID from the filename and store that in a variable. I am unsure how I would do this. It seems that a Script Task would suffice but I am do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are using Expressions on SSIS Variables or using a Script Task. As a general rule, I prefer Expressions but mentally, I can tell that's a lot of code, or a lot of intertwined variables.

Instead, I'd use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method in .NET. If you called the Split method for your sample data and provided a delimiter of the underscore `_` then you'd receive a 3 element array

- 12345
- Dell
- 20110103.CSV

Wrap that in a Try Catch block and always grab the second element. Quick and dirty but of course won't address things like `12345_Dell_Quest_20110103.CSV` but you didn't ask that question.

Code approximate

```
    string phrase = Dts.Variables["User::CurrentFile"].Value.ToString()
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"-"};
    string[] words;
    try
    {
        words = phrase.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Dts.Variables["User::ClientName"].Value = words[1];
    }
    catch
    {
        ; // Do something with this error
    }
```